# Insert data inner join Cakephp 3.0

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to CakePHP, I just finished the blog/article tutorial and now I am trying to add the comment system to it.

In my `comments` table I have, `Id`, `article_Id`, `name`, `email`, `text` and `created`. In my `articles` table I have `Id`, `user_id`, `title`, `text`, `created`.

I'm trying to add the comment according to the article ID by using Insert Inner join Query. So let's say a user views a specific article like `/view/1`, before he add comments, the article ID is already passed so he can comment accordingly to that specific article ID he is viewing. How can I do that? I hope I'm clear.

This is my add function for my comment:

```
public function leavemessage()
{
    $comment = $this->Comments->newEntity();
    $articles = $this->loadModel('Articles');
    $leavemessage = $articles->find()
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->join([
            'table' => 'comments',
            'alias' => 'c',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'c.article_id = articles.id',
        ])
        ->insert(['id'])
        ->where(['c.article_id = articles.id'])
        ->execute();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $comment = $this->Comments->patchEntity($comment, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Comments->save($comment)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The comment has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect([
                'controller' => 'Articles',
                'action' => 'index',
                'c.article_id'
            ]);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The comment could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $articles = $this->Comments->Articles->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('comment', 'articles'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['comment']);
}
```

My add comments view

```
<div class="comments form large-10 medium-9 columns">
    <?= $this->Form->create($comment); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Comment') ?></legend>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('article_id', ['value' => $articleId]);
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('text');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```